# Qt linking errors

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012, linker, static-linking

I’m trying to compile my first Qt project, but I have problems with unresolved extrnals when I link it. This is the full error log: http://pastebin.com/KpjvFKfu

```
Qt5Gui.lib(qdrawhelper_sse2.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * __cdecl std::_Winerror_map(int)" (?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z)
Qt5Gui.lib(qdrawhelper_avx.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * __cdecl std::_Winerror_map(int)" (?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z)
Qt5Gui.lib(qdrawhelper_ssse3.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * __cdecl std::_Winerror_map(int)" (?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z)
Qt5Gui.lib(Qt5Gui_pch.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * __cdecl std::_Winerror_map(int)" (?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z)
Qt5Gui.lib(qimage_avx.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * __cdecl std::_Winerror_map(int)" (?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z)
Qt5Gui.lib(qimage_sse2.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * __cdecl std::_Winerror_map(int)" (?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z)
Qt5Gui.lib(qimage_ssse3.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * __cdecl std::_Winerror_map(int)" (?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z)
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * __cdecl std::_Winerror_map(int)" (?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z)
.....
```

I'm using Qt compiled with VS2012 ×86 (compiled with -MT parameter). My program is also compiled with the same compiler and linked statically. I link with these Qt-related libraries: Qt5Core.lib Qt5Gui.lib Qt5Widgets.lib qtmain.lib

Do I need some more libraries to include or are there some other dependencies which I missed? How can I fix these errors?